# rstudio making a new column by comparing two other columns (alphebet)

Tags: r, sorting

as a beginner in R, I am having an issue with making a column.

I have a table of students' grades based on points and percentile.

let's say I have something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNkB.png)
I wish to create a new column called Finalgrade. And to do so, I would like to compare these two columns and assign the higher grade as finalgrade. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the grading system has a sequence like below

```
grade_seq <- c('A', 'AB', 'B', 'BC', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
```

then

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(Finalgrade = grade_seq[pmin(match(Gradepoints, grade_seq), match(Gradepercentile, grade_seq))])
```

gives

```
  Gradepoints Gradepercentile Finalgrade
1           A               B          A
2           A               D          A
3           F               D          D
4           F               F          F
5          AB              BC         AB
6          AB               C         AB
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Gradepoints = c('A','A','F','F','AB','AB'),
                 Gradepercentile = c('B','D','D','F','BC','C'))
```